# UIProgressbar in Cococa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiprogressbar

I want to display an UIProgressbar depending on the amount of data downloaded from the server.

One way I implemented is I made a NSURLConnection and set the delegate.
 The - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 gave me the expectedContentLengh

And in the - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 I am getting the data part by part every time until all the data are downloaded.

But this did not solve my problem.

Is there any other way to do this ?

All your suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the expected content length, just keep a running total of how much you've received so far divided by the total amount you'll get:

```
// These should be properties of the delegate class
UIProgressView * progressView;
long long expected;
long long gotSoFar; 

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    gotSoFar += data.length;
    progressView.progress = gotSofar / expected;
}
```

If you get type warnings on the division, cast each long long before doing the division.